# java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED on java.lang.Object

Tags: java, multithreading, deadlock

My application batch jobs hung without any errors in the logs. When the jobs are hung, there will be no database updates or inserts and I can see database blocks as well at the same time. Nothing happens in the system and everything seems stuck. See the complete thread dump I have taken during the issue time. Please help me to understand if this is the code problem or any external factors causing this hung in batch jobs. As a temporary workaround, I kill the database blocks or restart java wrapper service sometimes. It is really frustrating users many times. Thanks much in advance.

```
2013-05-14 06:29:37
Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (17.1-b03 mixed mode):

"Thread-35184" - Thread t@70107
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at com.ocs.util.Timer.run(Unknown Source)
   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"RMI TCP Connection(5)-153.88.251.56" - Thread t@70104
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at sun.management.ThreadImpl.dumpThreads0(Native Method)
    at sun.management.ThreadImpl.dumpAllThreads(ThreadImpl.java:374)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.ConvertingMethod.invokeWithOpenReturn(ConvertingMethod.java:167)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MXBeanIntrospector.invokeM2(MXBeanIntrospector.java:96)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MXBeanIntrospector.invokeM2(MXBeanIntrospector.java:33)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanIntrospector.invokeM(MBeanIntrospector.java:208)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.PerInterface.invoke(PerInterface.java:120)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanSupport.invoke(MBeanSupport.java:262)
    at javax.management.StandardMBean.invoke(StandardMBean.java:391)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:836)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:761)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1427)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$200(RMIConnectionImpl.java:72)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1265)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1360)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:788)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor181.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:305)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:159)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:155)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:535)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:790)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:649)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - locked java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync@7e8ed1b5

"JMX server connection timeout 70101" - Thread t@70101
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING on [I@38a76cf2
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at com.sun.jmx.remote.internal.ServerCommunicatorAdmin$Timeout.run(ServerCommunicatorAdmin.java:150)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"RMI Scheduler(0)" - Thread t@70099
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING on java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@77e1a0ec
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:198)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2025)
    at java.util.concurrent.DelayQueue.take(DelayQueue.java:164)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:609)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:602)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:947)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:907)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Batch Job Detail ThreadPROCESS_BATCH_UPGRADESMU" - Thread t@69553
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED on java.lang.Object@7e0c2370 owned by: Batch Job Detail ThreadPROCESS_BATCH_UPGRADESSU
    at com.ocs.poetic.activation.BatchUpgradeProcess.prepareBatchUpgradeData(Unknown Source)
    at com.ocs.poetic.activation.BatchUpgradeDetailProcess.process(Unknown Source)
    at com.ocs.poetic.batch.BatchJobDetailProcess.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.ocs.poetic.batch.BatchJobDetailProcess.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at com.ocs.framework.server.AppServerThread.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.ocs.framework.server.AppServerThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at com.ocs.framework.server.AppServerThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
    at com.ocs.framework.server.AppServerThread.run(Unknown Source)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - locked java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync@63f916cb

"Batch Job Detail ThreadPROCESS_BATCH_UPGRADESMU" - Thread t@69549
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED on java.lang.Object@7e0c2370 owned by: Batch Job Detail ThreadPROCESS_BATCH_UPGRADESSU
    at com.ocs.poetic.activation.BatchUpgradeProcess.prepareBatchUpgradeData(Unknown Source)
    at com.ocs.poetic.activation.BatchUpgradeDetailProcess.process(Unknown Source)
    at com.ocs.poetic.batch.BatchJobDetailProcess.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.ocs.poetic.batch.BatchJobDetailProcess.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at com.ocs.framework.server.AppServerThread.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.ocs.framework.server.AppServerThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at com.ocs.framework.server.AppServerThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
    at com.ocs.framework.server.AppServerThread.run(Unknown Source)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - locked java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync@76479cb3

"Batch Job Detail ThreadPROCESS_BATCH_UPGRADESMU" - Thread t@69545
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED on java.lang.Object@7e0c2370 owned by: Batch Job Detail ThreadPROCESS_BATCH_UPGRADESSU
    at com.ocs.poetic.activation.BatchUpgradeProcess.prepareBatchUpgradeData(Unknown Source)
    at com.ocs.poetic.activation.BatchUpgradeDetailProcess.process(Unknown Source)
    at com.ocs.poetic.batch.BatchJobDetailProcess.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.ocs.poetic.batch.BatchJobDetailProcess.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at com.ocs.framework.server.AppServerThread.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.ocs.framework.server.AppServerThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at com.ocs.framework.server.AppServerThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
    at com.ocs.framework.server.AppServerThread.run(Unknown Source)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - locked java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync@5780e86f

"Batch Lane Thread (JobName - PROCESS_BATCH_UPGRADES QueuePubID - MU)" - Thread t@69541
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING on java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync@4eeaceb6
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:198)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1011)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.tryAcquireSharedNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:227)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:91)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.invokeAll(AbstractExecutorService.java:251)
    at com.ocs.poetic.batch.BatchJobProcess.processEventDetails(Unknown Source)
    at com.ocs.poetic.batch.BatchJobProcess.process(Unknown Source)
    at com.ocs.poetic.batch.BatchJobLane.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.ocs.poetic.batch.BatchJobLane.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at com.ocs.framework.server.AppServerThread.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.ocs.framework.server.AppServerThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at com.ocs.framework.server.AppServerThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
    at com.ocs.framework.server.AppServerThread.run(Unknown Source)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - locked java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync@501bfc4a

"Batch Job Detail ThreadPROCESS_BATCH_UPGRADESSU" - Thread t@69431
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:129)
    at com.inet.tds.w.b(Unknown Source)
    at com.inet.tds.k.d(Unknown Source)
    at com.inet.tds.k.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.inet.tds.k.b(Unknown Source)
    at com.inet.tds.k.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.inet.tds.k.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.inet.tds.af.a(Unknown Source)
    - locked com.inet.tds.an@5d50875c
    at com.inet.tds.u.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
    at com.ocs.framework.transactpersist.sql.PoeticPreparedStatement.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
    at com.ocs.framework.transactpersist.jdbc.JDBCDataAccess.executeStatement(Unknown Source)
    at com.ocs.framework.transactpersist.RelationalEntityPersistence.restoreEntity(Unknown Source)
    at com.ocs.framework.transactpersist.Entity.restore(Unknown Source)
    at com.ocs.framework.transactpersist.Entity.restore(Unknown Source)
    at com.ocs.poetic.activation.UpgradeActivationUtil.updateValidateEntitlementList(Unknown Source)
    at com.ocs.poetic.activation.UpgradeActivationUtil.updateValidationProductMsg(Unknown Source)
    at com.ocs.poetic.activation.BatchUpgradeProcess.prepareBatchUpgradeData(Unknown Source)
    - locked java.lang.Object@7e0c2370
    at com.ocs.poetic.activation.BatchUpgradeDetailProcess.process(Unknown Source)
    at com.ocs.poetic.batch.BatchJobDetailProcess.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.ocs.poetic.batch.BatchJobDetailProcess.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at com.ocs.framework.server.AppServerThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at com.ocs.framework.server.AppServerThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
    at com.ocs.framework.server.AppServerThread.run(Unknown Source)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - locked java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync@51e6d8e0

"Batch Job Detail ThreadPROCESS_BATCH_UPGRADESSU" - Thread t@69427
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED on java.lang.Object@7e0c2370 owned by: Batch Job Detail ThreadPROCESS_BATCH_UPGRADESSU
    at com.ocs.poetic.activation.BatchUpgradeProcess.rollbackEntitlementData(Unknown Source)
    at com.ocs.poetic.activation.BatchUpgradeDetailProcess.process(Unknown Source)
    at com.ocs.poetic.batch.BatchJobDetailProcess.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.ocs.poetic.batch.BatchJobDetailProcess.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at com.ocs.framework.server.AppServerThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at com.ocs.framework.server.AppServerThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
    at com.ocs.framework.server.AppServerThread.run(Unknown Source)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - locked java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync@aa88422

"Batch Job Detail ThreadPROCESS_BATCH_UPGRADESSU" - Thread t@69376
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED on java.lang.Object@7e0c2370 owned by: Batch Job Detail ThreadPROCESS_BATCH_UPGRADESSU
    at com.ocs.poetic.activation.BatchUpgradeProcess.prepareBatchUpgradeData(Unknown Source)
    at com.ocs.poetic.activation.BatchUpgradeDetailProcess.process(Unknown Source)
    at com.ocs.poetic.batch.BatchJobDetailProcess.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.ocs.poetic.batch.BatchJobDetailProcess.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at com.ocs.framework.server.AppServerThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at com.ocs.framework.server.AppServerThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
    at com.ocs.framework.server.AppServerThread.run(Unknown Source)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - locked java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync@3d7ad9a5

"Batch Job Detail ThreadPROCESS_BATCH_UPGRADESSU" - Thread t@69372
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED on java.lang.Object@7e0c2370 owned by: Batch Job Detail ThreadPROCESS_BATCH_UPGRADESSU
    at com.ocs.poetic.activation.BatchUpgradeProcess.prepareBatchUpgradeData(Unknown Source)
    at com.ocs.poetic.activation.BatchUpgradeDetailProcess.process(Unknown Source)
    at com.ocs.poetic.batch.BatchJobDetailProcess.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.ocs.poetic.batch.BatchJobDetailProcess.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at com.ocs.framework.server.AppServerThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at com.ocs.framework.server.AppServerThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
    at com.ocs.framework.server.AppServerThread.run(Unknown Source)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - locked java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync@4c66ff2b

"Batch Lane Thread (JobName - PROCESS_BATCH_UPGRADES QueuePubID - SU)" - Thread t@69368
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING on java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync@19a93734
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:198)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1011)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.tryAcquireSharedNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:227)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:91)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.invokeAll(AbstractExecutorService.java:251)
    at com.ocs.poetic.batch.BatchJobProcess.processEventDetails(Unknown Source)
    at com.ocs.poetic.batch.BatchJobProcess.pollEventDetails(Unknown Source)
    at com.ocs.poetic.batch.BatchJobProcess.process(Unknown Source)
    at com.ocs.poetic.batch.BatchJobLane.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.ocs.poetic.batch.BatchJobLane.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at com.ocs.framework.server.AppServerThread.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.ocs.framework.server.AppServerThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at com.ocs.framework.server.AppServerThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
    at com.ocs.framework.server.AppServerThread.run(Unknown Source)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - locked java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync@7dfa873c

"Batch Job Detail ThreadPROCESS_BATCH_UPGRADESMU" - Thread t@69341
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED on java.lang.Object@7e0c2370 owned by: Batch Job Detail ThreadPROCESS_BATCH_UPGRADESSU
    at com.ocs.poetic.activation.BatchUpgradeProcess.prepareBatchUpgradeData(Unknown Source)
    at com.ocs.poetic.activation.BatchUpgradeDetailProcess.process(Unknown Source)
    at com.ocs.poetic.batch.BatchJobDetailProcess.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.ocs.poetic.batch.BatchJobDetailProcess.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at com.ocs.framework.server.AppServerThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at com.ocs.framework.server.AppServerThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
    at com.ocs.framework.server.AppServerThread.run(Unknown Source)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - locked java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync@4ac4b4c1

"Batch Job Detail ThreadPROCESS_BATCH_UPGRADESMU" - Thread t@69337
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED on java.lang.Object@7e0c2370 owned by: Batch Job Detail ThreadPROCESS_BATCH_UPGRADESSU
    at com.ocs.poetic.activation.BatchUpgradeProcess.prepareBatchUpgradeData(Unknown Source)
    at com.ocs.poetic.activation.BatchUpgradeDetailProcess.process(Unknown Source)
    at com.ocs.poetic.batch.BatchJobDetailProcess.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.ocs.poetic.batch.BatchJobDetailProcess.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at com.ocs.framework.server.AppServerThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at com.ocs.framework.server.AppServerThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
    at com.ocs.framework.server.AppServerThread.run(Unknown Source)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - locked java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync@38371140

"Batch Job Detail ThreadPROCESS_BATCH_UPGRADESMU" - Thread t@69333
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED on java.lang.Object@7e0c2370 owned by: Batch Job Detail ThreadPROCESS_BATCH_UPGRADESSU
    at com.ocs.poetic.activation.BatchUpgradeProcess.prepareBatchUpgradeData(Unknown Source)
    at com.ocs.poetic.activation.BatchUpgradeDetailProcess.process(Unknown Source)
    at com.ocs.poetic.batch.BatchJobDetailProcess.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.ocs.poetic.batch.BatchJobDetailProcess.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at com.ocs.framework.server.AppServerThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at com.ocs.framework.server.AppServerThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
    at com.ocs.framework.server.AppServerThread.run(Unknown Source)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - locked java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync@274d9d95

"Batch Lane Thread (JobName - PROCESS_BATCH_UPGRADES QueuePubID - MU)" - Thread t@69329
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING on java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync@34674415
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:198)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1011)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.tryAcquireSharedNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:227)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:91)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.invokeAll(AbstractExecutorService.java:251)
    at com.ocs.poetic.batch.BatchJobProcess.processEventDetails(Unknown Source)
    at com.ocs.poetic.batch.BatchJobProcess.pollEventDetails(Unknown Source)
    at com.ocs.poetic.batch.BatchJobProcess.process(Unknown Source)
    at com.ocs.poetic.batch.BatchJobLane.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.ocs.poetic.batch.BatchJobLane.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at com.ocs.framework.server.AppServerThread.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.ocs.framework.server.AppServerThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at com.ocs.framework.server.AppServerThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
    at com.ocs.framework.server.AppServerThread.run(Unknown Source)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - locked java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync@257e96d4

"Batch Lane Thread (JobName - PROCESS_BATCH_UPGRADES QueuePubID - SU)" - Thread t@69292
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING on java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync@67a6d993
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:198)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1011)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.tryAcquireSharedNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:227)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:91)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.invokeAll(AbstractExecutorService.java:251)
    at com.ocs.poetic.batch.BatchJobProcess.processEventDetails(Unknown Source)
    at com.ocs.poetic.batch.BatchJobProcess.pollEventDetails(Unknown Source)
    at com.ocs.poetic.batch.BatchJobProcess.process(Unknown Source)
    at com.ocs.poetic.batch.BatchJobLane.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.ocs.poetic.batch.BatchJobLane.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at com.ocs.framework.server.AppServerThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at com.ocs.framework.server.AppServerThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
    at com.ocs.framework.server.AppServerThread.run(Unknown Source)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - locked java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync@19e04b87

"Batch Queue Thread (PROCESS_BATCH_UPGRADES)" - Thread t@69288
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at com.ocs.poetic.batch.BatchJobQueue.checkLaneStatus(Unknown Source)
    at com.ocs.poetic.batch.BatchJobQueue.processEvents(Unknown Source)
    at com.ocs.poetic.batch.BatchJobQueue.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at com.ocs.framework.server.AppServerThread.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.ocs.framework.server.AppServerThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at com.ocs.framework.server.AppServerThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
    at com.ocs.framework.server.AppServerThread.run(Unknown Source)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - locked java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync@547e9956

"Batch Queue Thread (PROCESS_BATCH_UPGRADES)" - Thread t@69284
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at com.ocs.poetic.batch.BatchJobQueue.checkLaneStatus(Unknown Source)
    at com.ocs.poetic.batch.BatchJobQueue.processEvents(Unknown Source)
    at com.ocs.poetic.batch.BatchJobQueue.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at com.ocs.framework.server.AppServerThread.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.ocs.framework.server.AppServerThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at com.ocs.framework.server.AppServerThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
    at com.ocs.framework.server.AppServerThread.run(Unknown Source)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - locked java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync@43850870

"Batch Queue Thread (PROCESS_BATCH_UPGRADES)" - Thread t@69280
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at com.ocs.poetic.batch.BatchJobQueue.checkLaneStatus(Unknown Source)
    at com.ocs.poetic.batch.BatchJobQueue.processEvents(Unknown Source)
    at com.ocs.poetic.batch.BatchJobQueue.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at com.ocs.framework.server.AppServerThread.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.ocs.framework.server.AppServerThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at com.ocs.framework.server.AppServerThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
    at com.ocs.framework.server.AppServerThread.run(Unknown Source)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - locked java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync@52ed13b1

"AWT-Windows" - Thread t@10846
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at sun.awt.windows.WToolkit.eventLoop(Native Method)
    at sun.awt.windows.WToolkit.run(WToolkit.java:293)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Java2D Disposer" - Thread t@7165
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING on java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock@7b16770e
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:118)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:134)
    at sun.java2d.Disposer.run(Disposer.java:127)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Sequence ID Retriever Thread" - Thread t@116
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING on java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@7fe27743
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:158)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1987)
    at java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue.take(ArrayBlockingQueue.java:317)
    at com.ocs.framework.server.AppServerThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(Unknown Source)
    at com.ocs.framework.server.AppServerThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
    at com.ocs.framework.server.AppServerThread.run(Unknown Source)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"QuartzScheduler_PoeticBGScheduler-esessmw0521.ss.sw.ericsson.se:5866_MisfireHandler" - Thread t@108
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$MisfireHandler.run(JobStoreSupport.java:3840)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None
```

Comment: Your code has a deadlock.

Answer (score 2):

Many of your threads are waiting for the same lock `java.lang.Object@7e0c2370`:

```
java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED on java.lang.Object@7e0c2370
```

which is held by

```
"Batch Job Detail ThreadPROCESS_BATCH_UPGRADESSU" - Thread t@69431
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:129)
    ...
    - locked com.inet.tds.an@5d50875c
    at com.inet.tds.u.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
    ...
    - locked java.lang.Object@7e0c2370
    at com.ocs.poetic.activation.BatchUpgradeDetailProcess.process(Unknown Source)
    ...
```

So it seems that this latter thread is reading from a socket while holding a lock, which prevents all other threads from making progress.

Comment: Thanks you so much for the response. I am checking the same with my Product Vendor.

Comment: Hi, I have checked with my product vendor and they have done the necessary code fixes to avoid the blocks shown in above thread dump. Thank you so much for your review comments.